# Cancelling effect of a system on a signal

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

I have a signal `A` and It's been transformed using an unknown system to a signal `A'`. I also have another output signal `B'` from the same system and I want to retrieve the corresponding input signal `B`.
I wanted to first calculate the frequency response of the system, and then divide the Fourier transformed version of `B'` by it. Is this a good way?
`H(w) = A'(w) / A(w)` and then `B(w) = B'(w) / H(w)` and then I can perform inverse Fourier transform on the `B(w)`. Is this a good and practical way? because I'm trying to do it in python or Matlab and I want it to be both theoretically and practically correct(I am a bit confused about doing the division part in my code.)

Comment: Consider asking the question here: [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Irreducible Thank's! Didn't know it exists.